# How to get vue template to run before script?

Tags: javascript, canvas, vue.js

I'm setting up a ascii camera using vue, I've come across this problem while trying to access the canvas from template. in `bootCanvas()` when I try to access the canvas using `this.context = this.$ref.canvas.getContext('2d')` I get an error saying `"Cannot read property 'canvas' of undefined"` even though I've declared it in the template

I'm 90% sure that the cause of the error is that the script is running before the template, but I'm very new to vue so I might be missing out something very obvious here and this might not be the problem at all

my code is as follows :

```
<template>
    <div v-if="error === null">
     <p v-if = "stream === null">
       Please allow acces to your camera when prompted
     </p>
     <p v-else>
     <video class="video" v-bind:src="stream" ref:video autoplay></video>
     <canvas class="canvas" ref:canvas ></canvas>
     </p>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
      {{ error }}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      //where out errors will be held
      error: null,
      //where our stream will be held
      stream: null,
      //for html canvas
      context: null,
      //ascii options
      ascii: {
        contrast: 30,
        fps: 30
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    //access webcam
    initVideo () {
      navigator.getUserMedia({
        //we want video but not audio
        video: true,
        audio: false
      }, (stream) => {
        //get the webcam stream
        this.stream = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream)

        this.bootCanvas().then(() => {
          this.startAsciiRendering()
        })
        //throw error if failed
      }, this.setError)
    },
    startAsciiRendering () {
      setInterval(() => {
        alert('run')
        // console.log('run')
      }, Math.round(1000 / this.ascii.fps))
    },
    bootCanvas () {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.context = this.$ref.canvas.getContext('2d')
        //video dimensions
        this.$refs.canvas.width = 200
        this.$refs.canvas.height = 150
      })

      resolve()
    },
    //errors
    setUnsupported () {
      this.error = 'Your browser does not support video :(';
    },
    setError () {
      this.error = 'Something went wrong, try refreshing the page';
    }
  },
  //mounted = when page loads
  mounted () {
    //check if able to get webcam
    if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
      this.initVideo()
    } else  {
      this.setUnsupported()
    }
  }
}
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped lang="sass">
  html, body
    width: 100%
    height: 100%
    margin: 0
    padding: 0

  .video
    width: 200px
    position: fixed
    top: 0
    left: 0
    z-index: 1
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

v-else was preventing element from rendering.

Comment: it is originally $refs in my code. not sure how it ended up being refs here. still not working either way. any other idea?

Comment: Are you using Vue 1 or 2

Comment: I'm using vue 2

Comment: I don't think that syntax will work anymore, try updating the template to ref="canvas"

Comment: Also it looks like your calling resolve outside of your promise

Comment: good catch on the promise. I tried ref="canvas" and it's still the same thing. I thought it would be ref:canvas since in here https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#v-el-and-v-ref-replaced it says that it got replaced so I assumed that the syntax would be same

Comment: so now its     <canvas class="canvas" ref="canvas" ></canvas> and same exact error is thrown

Comment: You may just need to set a breakpoint in dev tools and see what 'this' looks like

Comment: console.log(this.$refs) shows that my canvas ref is inside of it. but this.$refs.canvas is undefined. is $refs.canvas the right syntax to get refs inside $refs?

Comment: Yea that's the right way to get it,  could it be one of your v-ifs preventing the element from rendering

Comment: Actually that's probably it, you may need to use $nextTick after setting steam so the UI has time to update

Comment: oh god, that was it! I got rid of the else block from stream === null and now it's working. thanks for your help man

Comment: Np, it's the little stuff that gets ya ☺️